# iOS 6.0 Storyboard: Set static cell selected

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, storyboard, ios6

I have created 5 static cells in UITableViewController scene. Everything working fine but I am not able to set the particular cell selected! If it is prototype cell then its simple but how could I set static cell selected? Following code raises BAD memory access exception! I have done this based on [discussion on apple thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/505098) but not sure what's wrong! Could someone help please.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(indexPath.section == _rating)
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this. I have to return UITableViewCell return type and have to used this method like below. It was recursive calling the methods and hence was failing.

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(indexPath.section == _rating)
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    return cell;
 }
```